# How to Permanently Save a URL in Swift 3

Tags: url, swift3

I am currently trying  to use two buttons in my Swift application. I'm using one button to save the current URL of my web view and the other button to load the most recently saved URL. We can call these Buttons 1 and 2. I do not know how to save the URL permanently so that if the user restarts the app Button 2 will still be able to load the page that was last saved. I've looked on Google and Youtube but I'm struggling to find a tutorial for Swift 3 and Xcode 8. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest is to save the URL in `UserDefaults`.

```
var url = ... // the URL you wish to save
UserDefaults.standard.set(url, forKey: "MyApp.lastURL")
```

And then to load the URL when your app starts again,

```
var lastURL = UserDefaults.standard.url(forKey: "MyApp.lastURL")
```

Note that `lastURL` will be optional and will be `nil` if no previous URL has been saved.